# webpack-dev-server electron angular 1.6.1 hot reload blank screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server

Im currently learning Electron, I created a simple app in Angular with webpack to livereload. However on hot reload the app loads a blank view, *see screenshot below, and I have to restart electron to get it back. I have done a similar app in React, and it works fine.

I put the code up on a repo https://github.com/graemec23/Favourite-places-ng1

I would be grateful for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was because of html5Mode in Angular ui-router, it requires a server and does not work on file:// protocol. Setting enabled to false solved it.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: false,
  requireBase: false,
});
```